# Construct an open hardware laptop without Intel Management Engine (ME)

Tags: bios, uefi

The [Free Software Foundation](https://www.fsf.org) offers a [laptop that is 100% open hardware](https://www.fsf.org/news/libreboot-t400-laptop-now-fsf-certified-to-respect-your-freedom)

> The Libreboot T400 is a refurbished and updated laptop based on the Lenovo ThinkPad T400... in order to achieve the Free Software Foundation's RYF certification guidelines, Minifree had to replace the low-level firmware ... The free software boot system of Libreboot and the GNU GRUB 2 bootloader were adapted to replace the stock proprietary firmware, which included a BIOS and Intel's Management Engine firmware.

This sounds very easy to achieve on any laptop, isn't it? Why are there only three devices certified by the FSF?

What steps are needed to free a Laptop from Intel ME, BIOS and UEFI?

Comment: The Intel ME is a security risk, so a solution here world be a great increase of security

Comment: "*The Intel ME is a security risk*": this statement seems highly opinion and context based. Intel ME is a feature and not a vulnerability, the fact that you don't need this feature and therefore prefer to disable it to reduce your exposure is another story. I also think that there is a security trade-off here, since for instance the bundled TPM chip will most probably not be usable anymore (or at least should not be used to stay consistent with the pseudo 100% open source policy, I say pseudo because of other non-flashed firmwares like the hard disk, etc.).

Comment: While this subject may lead to interesting security questions, this, or should I say *these* questions (Is it easy to do? Why so few devices? How to do it?) are not directly on-topic for this site. For instance, why we do recommend to use a properly configured router to protect your home network for security reasons, which router to choose and how to configure the exact model you've chose are out-of-topic here. So while what you mention may indeed have security advantages/disadvantages in some specific situations, I think too that the questions your ask here are better suited for [su].

Comment: I was starting to check out how to block Intel ME after I heard this: http://hackaday.com/2015/12/28/32c3-towards-trustworthy-x86-laptops/

Comment: IMEI is disabled by default on all PCs requiring it's drivers.  IMEI has to be manually turned on, and if it is turned on, then yes, it can be a security risk.  IMEI is the PC version of a server board's  IPMI.

Answer (score 3):

Most (or maybe all) Intel processors since about 2008 have shipped with Intel ME. There is likely something about [the list of processors here](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:T400) that allows them to remove Intel ME. I assume later models/generations from Intel do not have this ability.

The reason there are only three models is presumably that they are relatively low in demand, largely in part because they're using 8 year old hardware.

[Here's a guide](http://libreboot.org/docs/install/t400_external.html) on flashing the T400.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the firmware is far from easy, at least as a general rule. The problem is that the firmware is necessarily written specifically for one motherboard, or at least one chipset -- the firmware for Chipset A will most likely hang, or at least perform poorly, if installed on Chipset B. I don't have an exact count, but there must have been hundreds (maybe thousands) of PC chipsets produced over the years. Searching at NewEgg, I see that they list 20 chipsets for currently-available Intel motherboards and 12 more for currently-available AMD motherboards.

At the moment, the premiere solution for open source (or close to it) replacement firmware is [CoreBoot.](https://www.coreboot.org/) This provides a toolkit for building a simple hardware-initialization core, atop which you can fit any of several "payloads" to provide functionality -- for instance, an open source BIOS, an open source UEFI, GRUB, or a Linux kernel. The CoreBoot [supported motherboards list](https://www.coreboot.org/Supported_Motherboards) is rather small compared to the total history of x86 PCs. (Of course, CoreBoot is likely to work on a wider range of hardware than the officially-supported list, but you'll be trail-blazing if you want to try it on something not on the list.)

This is of course a problem for those, such as Richard Stallman, who are ideologically opposed to proprietary software; most computers are dependent on proprietary firmware, even if they run a fully open source OS and application stack. Although CoreBoot is an option for some, it's obscure enough, untested enough, and limited enough in supported computers that it will severely limit your hardware choices and probably require a good deal of extra effort if you insist on using it. Most people don't care enough to go to any hassle to get rid of the proprietary firmware. For those who do, the limitations of CoreBoot *are* an issue; you can't just drop in CoreBoot as a replacement the way you can drop Linux onto a computer as a replacement for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the other stuff on your list, but I know you can remove the critical bits of Intel's Management Engine (kernel, network stack, etc) with a Python script called me_cleaner. Here's a link: https://github.com/corna/me_cleaner

Once you get rid of those important parts of Intel's ME, you can be pretty confident (if not entirely confident) that your laptop's firmware is secure.